# Missing System.Devices library and problem constructing AQS strings

Tags: c#, uwp

What I am trying to achieve is to scan my loacal network for connected devices. I learned that I need to construct a selector and pass it to function

```
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()
```

for example. The problem is, however, all of these require the System.Devices namespace e.g.

```
System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{2eef81be-33fa-4800-9670-1cd474972c3f}"
```

and I get such an error: "Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Devices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

I suspect this is because I'm missing the library somehow. I tried
    using System.Devices
but again namespace does not exist in the namespace. I also tried adding it in the Reference Manager but there is no such library either.
I couldn't find the library online.

Also I am not exactly sure how to construct AQS strings.

```
DeviceInformationCollection collection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.ImageScanner);
```

This is ok but showing local devices only.

```
var selector = System.Device.Aep.ProtocolId:= "{37aba761-2124-454c-8d82-c42962c2de2b}";
```

This gives errors, one with namespace and more syntax-bound.

I expect passing a selector to the function but I'm missing the namespace System.Devices and AQS strings don't work.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like this is not a namespace. They are windows properties, please check windows properties.

`System.Devices` is not a namespace. They are [**Device information properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties). if your want enumerate device, you need use `DeviceWatcher` to capture device that match condition.

```
DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
        "", // AQS Filter string
        null, // requested properties
        deviceInfoKind);
```

And this is [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) that you could refer.

Comment: But how do I build the string? Just "{2eef81be-33fa-4800-9670-1cd474972c3f}" gives an exception.

Comment: What's exception? This format id is related to microphone device.

Answer (score 0):

"DeviceWatcher" sounds great — it says:

"Build the sample

```
Start Visual Studio and select File > Open > Project/Solution.
Go to the directory to which you unzipped the sample. Then go to the subdirectory containing the sample in the language you desire - either C++, C#, or JavaScript. Double-click the Visual Studio Solution (.sln) file.
Select the appropriate target: x86, x64, ARM. Press Ctrl+Shift+B, or select Build > Build Solution.
```

Ah, but then the catch comes:

"The type or namespace 'System' could not be found."

It supplies "using System;" in all the header lines, it but demands "using Windows;" and rejects all the others.

Go figure —